# Create array by sampling PDF

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a 2D array with numpy, where each entry at (x,y) is either 0 or 1, and the probability to get a 1 is defined by a PDF, for example a 2D gaussian.

The goal ist to be able to add many such arrays, and retrieve something like a histogram where I can see the 2D gaussian peak.

I've found many ways to sample a distribution (read: get back (x,y) pairs, where coordinates closer to (mu_x, mu_y) are more likely), but no easy way to fill an array. Is there any builtin function in numpy/scipy to do this, or do I have to do it by hand (e.g. by iterating over the array, and if `f(x,y) > threshold` set element to 1)?

For the uniform probability distribution, I can do:

```
np.random.randint(2, size=(30,30))
```

Any way to do this for a gaussian?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a build-in functionality for that but as you already suggested you can easily achieve what you want by comparing random numbers to a threshold. You should not iterate using something like a `for` loop though, as those are rather slow. I'd suggest to use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for the comparison. Here is an example:

First, we setup a grid, compute the thresholds for each gridpoint and plot the result for reference:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xEdges = np.linspace(0, 10, 31)
yEdges = np.linspace(0, 10, 31)
xMids = (xEdges[:-1]+xEdges[1:])/2.
yMids = (yEdges[:-1]+yEdges[1:])/2.
xMesh, yMesh = np.meshgrid(xMids, yMids)

rv = st.multivariate_normal(mean=[5, 5], cov=[[2,0],[0,2]])
threshold = rv.pdf(np.stack((xMesh, yMesh), axis=2))

plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.pcolormesh(xMesh, yMesh, threshold)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

Output (Bivariate Gaussian distribution with arbitrary normalization. I don't really understand what normalization you want comparing to your example but as this is just a factor, I just left is as is.):

[image]

Now we can compare an array of uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1 of the grid's shape against the threshold by use of `np.where`. When the condition is met, the corresponding entry in the result is set to 1, elseway to 0:

```
hist = np.where(np.random.rand(30, 30)<threshold, 1, 0)
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.pcolormesh(xMesh, yMesh, hist)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

Now after 1 try you can not really see, that it is working, but `hist` contains what you want:

[image]

```
for _ in range(9999):
    hist += np.where(np.random.rand(30, 30)<threshold, 1, 0)
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.pcolormesh(xMesh, yMesh, hist/10000.)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

After 10000 tries, you can already nicely see the distribution forming:

[image]

```
for _ in range(90000):
    hist += np.where(np.random.rand(30, 30)<threshold, 1, 0)
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.pcolormesh(xMesh, yMesh, hist/100000.)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

And averaging over 100000 tries, the distribution is next to indistinguishable from the analytic distribution function:

[image]